# Loop through an array of [Any]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I have an array with define as `Any` consist of user objects and every 60th elements there will be a string of "Yes". 
The array looks like below:

```
[user1,...user60,"Yes",user61,user62....,user119,"Yes"]
```

I wish to display cell 1 to cell 60 to be users from my array, when the item in array is "Yes", display another cell which just an image. Then the collection view will continue to grow according to the array.

Comment: What do you want to display in the CollectionView?

Comment: if you want to show the single users you could split it by your seperator, and remove the "Yes" ... if you wanna show the whole "user1,...user60" thing you can just split it by "Yes".

Comment: when the item is user1, display the user1, when it loop through the "Yes", display a big banner image.

Comment: Swift is strongly typed for a reason. Do yourself a favor and rethink your model. [Any] is the root of all evil.

Comment: @PriceRingo this is my solution for my project. And its my first time to use it.

Comment: So you are not looking for advise, but for code. We are not here to do your job. You question clearly shows a lake of research like the previous one. You don't even mark the answer that was helpful for you, pretty impolite...

Comment: @RomOne sorry guys, I am new here and new to Swift. Sorry for my courtesy.

Comment: No worries! Just next time put the research you have done on your question, or why you think it’s not working. That way people like me won’t complain :D

Comment: by using the iterate function below provided by friends here I can loop through the array, when I want to display on a collectionview, it will display 1 user to all the cells. How can I loop through the array with the help of the indexPath in cellForItemAt function with this array?

Comment: So do you want to display only users from your array in the collection view?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wish to display cell 1 to cell 60th would be users from my array, when the item in array is "Yes", display another cell which just an image. Then the collectionview will continue to grow  according to the array.

Comment: Answered it below, also I changed your question with what you wrote above since it was not obvious what you were trying to do. In future when you add clarifications to your questions you should just go and edit your question, since people cannot search through all comments to see what you really need...

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: I clicked, but my reputation is low to click and make it display on the page, sorry guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suppose that user1...user119 are of type `User` than you can do this:

```
let collection: [Any] = [user1,...user60,"Yes",user61,user62....,user119,"Yes"] 

for element in collection {
    if let user = element as? User {
        //do whatever you want with user class
    } else let yesString = element as? String, yesString == "Yes" {
        //you found "Yes" string
    } else {
       //unknown type
    }
}
```

You can use the same logic when you want to use the data in the collectionView data source, get the element from the array and do same as up to check if element is `User` or `String` with value of "Yes".

And since it is not clear from the question if you need "Yes" elements for the collection you can first remove "Yes"'es from the array and then you will have an array `[User]`.

Since your `collectionView` will have two types of cells: User cells and Image View cells you have to register them first to be used for the `collectionView` like:

```
self.collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "userCellIdent")
self.collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "yesCellIdent")
```

(If you have custom subclasses for each type, which most of the time you should just replace `UICollectionViewCell.self` with `YourCollectionViewCellSubclassName.self` for each cell type you wish to register)

In `cellForItemAt` you do:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let element = collection[indexPath.item]

    if let user = element as? User {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "userCellIdent", for: indexPath)
        //configure your cell with user data
        return cell
    } else if let yesString = element as? String, yesString == "Yes" {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "yesCellIdent", for: indexPath)
        //configure your with the image view when element in collection is "Yes"
        return cell
    } else {
        //you have something other than user and "Yes" in the collection
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

Comment: can he using while loop here ? @Ladislav

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi it all depends on what he wants to do, I generally do not use while loop if I want to iterate through entire array, I use for in for that. I would use while for example if I wanted to do something with the array elements until I hit a certain element that makes me stop for instance :)

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have successfully display the image view, but the weird thing is the 60th users also display in the image cell and all cells will shift their position when the list is bigger.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean...Update question with screenshots etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can Possibly use:

```
 let arrCollection: [Any] = [user1,...user60,"Yes",user61,user62....,user119,"Yes"]


    for data in arrCollection{

        if let strYes  == data as? String{
            print(strYes)
            print("yes found")

        }else{
            print("not Found")
        }
    }
```

Hope it Helps.